# Store LDAP bind credentials in environment variables for pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, authentication, pg-hba.conf, environment-variables, ldap

I am working on setting up LDAP authentication for a PostgreSQL database and have added the following in my `pg_hba.conf` file:

```bash
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER    ADDRESS     METHOD
host    all         all     all         ldap ldapurl="ldap://example.local/dc=example,dc=local?sAMAccountName" ldapbinddn="username" ldapbindpasswd="password"
```

It works! But now I'd like to store the username and password as environment variables, like I do for most of my config settings. I've tried adding the username and password as $LDAPUSERNAME or "$LDAPUSERNAME" but they aren't inserting any values. Is this possible?

Note: The database will be running in a docker container. If I have to run some script to process the `pg_hba.conf` file before starting the database, I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my final goal is to keep passwords out of version control and the database is running in a docker container, I made the image process the `pg_hba.conf` file on initialization.

1. Create a `.env` file for the service with the contents:

```
LDAPCONFIG=ldapurl="ldap://example.local/dc=example,dc=local?sAMAccountName" ldapbinddn="username" ldapbindpasswd="password"
```

Add this file to your `.gitignore` so it is not committed.

2. Edit the `pg_hba.conf` file with the environment variable:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER    ADDRESS     METHOD
host    all         all     all         ldap $LDAPCONFIG
```

3. Add the following script (I have saved under `scripts/ldap.sh`) and update the dockerfile to copy the script into the initialization directory:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Setting up pg_hba.conf file"
cat /var/tmp/pg_hba.conf | envsubst > /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

```
FROM postgres:14

RUN apt-get -y upgrade \
    && apt-get install -y gettext  # Dependency for envsubst command

COPY ./scripts/ldap.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10ldap.sh
COPY ./config/pg_hba.conf /var/tmp/pg_hba.conf
```

> Note: This script will only run if the data directory is empty, and you will have to run the script if the container already has a database.

Now simply start your database and watch for any errors in the log!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify these settings via environment variables in PostgreSQL. Remember that `ldapbindpasswd` is specific to a certain `pg_hba.conf` line, and different lines could have different settings.

Comment: Yup, and storing them as different variables for each connection would have been sufficient if the feature were available. Thank you!

Comment: I think there is a misconception. The whole processing is on the server, and an environment variable per connection can only be on the client.

Comment: The database is running inside a docker container, so the environment variables are all set from a config file. This is just the credentials to bind to the LDAP server. I want to keep the username and password out of git.

Comment: Use an LDAP user that has no sensitive permissions. How about anonymous bind?

Comment: Anonymous binding is disabled, but we have created a user with no important permissions. Thank you!